# Is it possible to edit source on SVN directory from Crucible?

Tags: svn, version-control, atlassian-fisheye, atlassian-crucible

In the same way that you can directly change the source and commit from the Github website, is it possible to make a change to the source manually on Crucible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think so. Atlassian Crucible is a code review tool. It is not a web client to version-control repositories. You may want to look for another product.